# Invalid outside procedure in excel vba with copied VBScript

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript

I am trying to run a [VBScript](https://bytes.com/topic/access/insights/965241-fuzzy-string-matching-double-metaphone-algorithm) as VBA code in a function in Excel:

```
Option Explicit

MsgBox(DoubleMetaphone(InputBox("Enter String"), 6))

Function DoubleMetaphone(strOriginal, intThreshhold)
    Dim isSlavoGermanic, strPrimary, strSecondary, i, intJump, iB
    Dim intLength, cP, cS, arr, x, intPad


isSlavoGermanic = False
iB = 4
intPad = 6
x = iB
intLength = Len(strOriginal) + iB - 1
strOriginal = UCase(strOriginal)

If (InStr(strOriginal, "W") + InStr(strOriginal, "K") + InStr(strOriginal, "CZ") + InStr(strOriginal, "WITZ")) <> 0 Then
    isSlavoGermanic = True
End If

ReDim arr(intLength + intPad + 1)

For i = 0 To iB-1
    arr(i) = vbTab
Next

For i = iB To intLength
    arr(i) = Mid(strOriginal, i-iB+1, 1)
Next

For i = intLength+1 To UBound(arr)
    arr(i) = vbTab
Next

Select Case (arr(x) & arr(x+1))
    Case "AC"
        strPrimary = "AKS"
        strSecondary = "AKS"
        x = x + 4
    Case "GN", "KN", "PN", "PS"
        x = x + 1
    Case "HA", "HE", "HI", "HO", "HU", "HY"
        strPrimary = "H"
        strSecondary = "H"
        x = x + 2
    Case "WA", "WE", "WI", "WO", "WU", "WY"
        strPrimary = "A"
        strSecondary = "F"
        x = x + 2
    Case "WH"
        strPrimary = "A"
        strSecondary = "A"
        x = x + 1
    Case "SM", "SN", "SL", "SW"
        strPrimary = "S"
        strSecondary = "X"
        x = x + 1
    Case "GY"
        strPrimary = "K"
        strSecondary = "J"
        x = x + 2
End Select

If x = iB Then
    If arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "JOSE" Then
        If (x = iB And arr(x+4) = " ") Then
            strPrimary = "HS"
            strSecondary = "HS"
            x = x + 4
        End If
    ElseIf arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "SUGAR" Then
        strPrimary = "XK"
        strSecondary = "SK"
        x = x + 5
    ElseIf arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) & arr(x+5) = "CAESAR" Then
        strPrimary = "SSR"
        strSecondary = "SSR"
        x = x + 6
    ElseIf (arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) & arr(x+5) = "CHARAC" Or _
    arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) & arr(x+5) = "CHARIS" Or _
    arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "CHOR" Or _
    arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "CHYM" Or _
    arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "CHEM") And _
    arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) <> "CHORE" Then
        strPrimary = "K"
        strSecondary = "K"
        x = x + 2
    End If
End If

If x = iB Then
    Select Case arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2)
        Case "GES", "GEP", "GEB", "GEL", "GEY", "GIB", "GIL", "GIN", "GIE", "GEI", "GER"
            strPrimary = "K"
            strSecondary = "J"
            x = x + 2
        Case "GHI"
            strPrimary = "J"
            strSecondary = "J"
            x = x + 3
        Case "AGN", "EGN", "IGN", "OGN", "UGN", "UGY"
            If Not isSlavoGermanic Then
                strPrimary = "AKN"
                strSecondary = "AN"
                x = x + 3
            End If
    End Select
End If

If x = iB Then
    Select Case arr(x)
        Case "X"
            strPrimary = "S"
            strSecondary = "S"
            x = x + 1
        Case "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"
            strPrimary = "A"
            strSecondary = "A"
            x = x + 1
        Case "J"
            strPrimary = "J"
            strSecondary = "A"
            x = x + 1
    End Select
End If

Do While x <= intLength
    If Len(strPrimary) >= intThreshhold Then
        Exit Do
    End If

    intJump = 1
    cP = arr(x)
    cS = arr(x)

    Select Case arr(x)
        Case "A", "E", "I", "O", "U", "Y"
            cP = ""
            cS = ""

        Case "B"
            cP = "P"
            cS = "P"

        Case "Ç"
            cP = "S"
            cS = "S"

        Case "C"
            If x > iB+1 And arr(x-2) <> "A" And arr(x-2) <> "E" And arr(x-2) <> "I" And arr(x-2) <> "O" And arr(x-2) <> "U" And _
            arr(x-2) <> "Y" And arr(x-1) & arr(x+1) = "AH" And ((arr(x+2) <> "I" And arr(x+2) <> "E") Or _
            arr(x-2) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "BER" Or arr(x-2) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "MER") Then
                cP = "K"
                cS = "K"
                intJump = 2
            ElseIf arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "HIA" Then
                cP = "K"
                cS = "K"
                intJump = 4
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "H" Then
                If x > iB And arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "AE" Then
                    cP = "K"
                    cS = "X"
                    intJump = 2
                ElseIf arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) = "VAN " Or _
                arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) = "VON " Or _
                arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) = "SCH" Or arr(x+2) = "T" Or arr(x+2) = "S" Or _
                arr(x-2) & arr(x-1) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "ORHES" Or _
                arr(x-2) & arr(x-1) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "ARHIT" Or _
                arr(x-2) & arr(x-1) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "ORHID" Or _ 
                ((arr(x-2) = "A" Or arr(x-2) = "E" Or arr(x-2) = "O" Or arr(x-2) = "U" Or x = iB) And _
                (arr(x+2) = "L" Or arr(x+2) = "R" Or arr(x+2) = "N" Or arr(x+2) = "M" Or arr(x+2) = "B" Or _
                arr(x+2) = "H" Or arr(x+2) = "F" Or arr(x+2) = "V" Or arr(x+2) = "W" Or arr(x+2) = " "))Then
                    cP = "K"
                    cS = "K"
                    intJump = 2
                Else
                    intJump = 2

                    If x > iB Then
                        If arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) = "MC" Then
                            cP = "K"
                            cS = "K"
                        Else
                            cP = "X"
                            cS = "K"
                        End If
                    Else
                        cP = "X"
                        cS = "X"
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "Z" And arr(x-2) & arr(x-1) <> "WI" Then
                cP = "S"
                cS = "X"
                intJump = 2
            ElseIf arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+2) = "CIA" Then
                cP = "X"
                cS = "X"
                intJump = 3
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "C" And Not (x = iB+1 And arr(iB) = "M") Then
                If (arr(x+2) = "I" Or arr(x+2) = "E" Or arr(x+2) = "H") And arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) <> "HU" Then
                    If arr(x-1) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "UCEE" Or _
                    arr(x-1) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "UCES" Then
                        cP = "KS"
                        cS = "KS"
                        intJump = 3
                    Else
                        cP = "X"
                        cS = "X"
                        intJump = 3
                    End If
                Else
                    cP = "K"
                    cS = "K"
                    intJump = 2
                End If
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "K" Or arr(x+1) = "G" Or arr(x+1) = "Q" Then
                cP = "K"
                cS = "K"
                intJump = 2
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "I" Or arr(x+1) = "E" Or arr(x+1) = "Y" Then
                If arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "IO" Or arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "IE" Or arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "IA" Then
                    cP = "S"
                    cS = "X"
                    intJump = 2
                Else
                    cP = "S"
                    cS = "S"
                    intJump = 2
                End If
            Else
                cP = "K"
                cS = "K"

                If arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = " C" Or arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = " Q" Or arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = " G" Then
                    intJump = 3
                Else
                    If (arr(x+1) = "C" Or arr(x+1) = "K" Or arr(x+1) = "Q") And _
                    arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) <> "CE" And arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) <> "CI" Then 
                        intJump = 2
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Case "D"
            If arr(x+1) = "G" Then
                If arr(x+2) = "I" Or _
                arr(x+2) = "E" Or _
                arr(x+2) = "Y" Then
                    cP = "J"
                    cS = "J"
                    intJump = 3
                Else
                    cP = "TK"
                    cS = "TK"
                    intJump = 2
                End If
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "T" Then
                cP = "T"
                cS = "T"
                intJump = 2
            Else
                cP = "T"
                cS = "T"
            End If

        Case "G"
            If arr(x+1) = "H" Then
                If x <> iB And arr(x-1) <> "A" And arr(x-1) <> "E" And arr(x-1) <> "I" _
                And arr(x-1) <> "O" And arr(x-1) <> "U" And arr(x-1) <> "Y" Then
                    cP = "K"
                    cS = "K"
                    intJump = 2
                ElseIf (x > iB+1 And (arr(x-2) = "B" Or arr(x-2) = "H" Or arr(x-2) = "D")) Or _
                (x > iB+2 And (arr(x-3) = "B" Or arr(x-3) = "H" Or arr(x-3) = "D")) Or _
                (x > iB+3 And (arr(x-4) = "B" Or arr(x-4) = "H")) Then
                    cP = ""
                    cS = ""
                    intJump = 2
                Else
                    If x > iB+2 And arr(x-1) = "U" And _
                    (arr(x-3) = "C" Or arr(x-3) = "G" Or arr(x-3) = "L" Or arr(x-3) = "R" Or arr(x-3) = "T") Then
                        cP = "F"
                        cS = "F"
                        intJump = 2
                    ElseIf x > iB And arr(x-1) <> "I" Then
                        cP = "K"
                        cS = "K"
                        intJump = 2
                    Else
                        cP = ""
                        cS = ""
                    End If
                End If
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "N" Then
                cS = "KN"
                intJump = 2

                If arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) <> "EY" And Not isSlavoGermanic Then
                    cP = "N"
                Else
                    cP = "KN"
                End If
            ElseIf arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "LI" And Not isSlavoGermanic Then
                cP = "KL"
                cS = "L"
                intJump = 2
            ElseIf (arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "ER" Or arr(x+1) = "Y") And _
            arr(x-1) <> "E" And arr(x-1) <> "I" And _
            arr(x-1) & arr(x+1) <> "RY" And _
            arr(x-1) & arr(x+1) <> "OY" And _
            arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) & arr(iB+4) & arr(iB+5) <> "DANGER" And _
            arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) & arr(iB+4) & arr(iB+5) <> "RANGER" And _
            arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) & arr(iB+4) & arr(iB+5) <> "MANGER" Then
                cP = "K"
                cS = "J"
                intJump = 2
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "E" Or arr(x+1) = "I" Or arr(x+1) = "Y" Or _
            arr(x-1) & arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "AGGI" Or _
            arr(x-1) & arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "OGGI" Then
                If arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) = "VON " Or _
                arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) = "VAN " Or _
                arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) = "SCH" Or _
                arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "ET" Then
                    cP = "K"
                    cS = "K"
                    intJump = 2
                Else
                    cP = "J"
                    If arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "IER " Then
                        cS = "J"
                        intJump = 3
                    Else
                        cS = "K"
                        intJump = 2
                    End If
                End If
            Else
                cP = "K"
                cS = "K"
            End If

        Case "H"
            If (arr(x-1) = "A" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "E" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "I" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "O" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "U" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "Y") And _
            (arr(x+1) = "A" Or _
            arr(x+1) = "E" Or _
            arr(x+1) = "I" Or _
            arr(x+1) = "O" Or _
            arr(x+1) = "U" Or _
            arr(x+1) = "Y") Then
                intJump = 2
            Else
                cP = ""
                cS = ""
            End If

        Case "J"
            If arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) = "SAN " Then
                cP = "H"
                cS = "H"
            Else
                If Not isSlavoGermanic And ( _
                arr(x-1) = "A" Or _
                arr(x-1) = "E" Or _
                arr(x-1) = "I" Or _
                arr(x-1) = "O" Or _
                arr(x-1) = "U" Or _
                arr(x-1) = "Y") And ( _
                arr(x+1) = "A" Or _
                arr(x+1) = "O") Then
                    cS = "H"
                Else
                    If x = intLength Then
                        cS = ""
                    Else
                        If arr(x+1) = "L" Or arr(x+1) = "T" Or arr(x+1) = "K" Or _
                        arr(x+1) = "S" Or arr(x+1) = "N" Or arr(x+1) = "M" Or _
                        arr(x+1) = "B" Or arr(x+1) = "Z" Or _
                        arr(x-1) = "S" Or arr(x-1) = "K" Or arr(x-1) = "L" Then
                            cP = ""
                            cS = ""
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If

        Case "L"
            If arr(x+1) = "L" Then
                intJump = 2

                If ((x = intLength-2 And ( _
                arr(x-1) & arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "ILLO" Or _
                arr(x-1) & arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "ILLA" Or _
                arr(x-1) & arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "ALLE" _
                )) Or (( _
                arr(intLength-1) & arr(intLength) = "AS" Or _
                arr(intLength-1) & arr(intLength) = "OS" Or _
                arr(intLength) = "A" Or arr(intLength) = "O") And _
                arr(x-1) & arr(x) & arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "ALLE")) Then
                    cS = ""
                End If
            End If

        Case "M"
            If arr(x-1) & arr(x) & arr(x+1) = "UMB" And _
            (x = intLength-1 Or arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "ER") Then
                intJump = 2
            End If

        Case "P"
            Select Case arr(x+1)
                Case "H"
                    cP = "F"
                    cS = "F"
                    intJump = 2
                Case "B"
                    intJump = 2
            End Select

        Case "Q"
            cP = "K"
            cS = "K"

        Case "R"
            If x = intLength And Not isSlavoGermanic And _
            arr(x-2) & arr(x-1) = "IE" And _
            arr(x-4) & arr(x-3) <> "ME" And _
            arr(x-4) & arr(x-3) <> "MA" Then
                cP = ""
            End If

        Case "S"
            If arr(x+1) = "L" And (arr(x-1) = "I" Or arr(x-1) = "Y") Then
                cP = ""
                cS = ""
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "H" And _
            arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) <> "EIM" And _
            arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) <> "OEK" And _
            arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) <> "OLM" And _
            arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) <> "OLZ" Then
                intJump = 2
                cP = "X"
                cS = "X"
            ElseIf Not isSlavoGermanic And ( _
            arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "IA" Or _
            arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "IO") Then
                intJump = 3
                cS = "X"
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "Z" Then
                cS = "X"
                intJump = 2
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "C" Then
                intJump = 3

                If arr(x+2) = "H" Then
                    If arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "OO" Or _
                    arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "ER" Or _
                    arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "EN" Or _
                    arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "UY" Or _
                    arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "ED" Or _
                    arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "EM" Then
                        cS = "SK"

                        If arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "ER" Or _
                        arr(x+3) & arr(x+4) = "EN" Then
                            cP = "X"
                        Else
                            cP = "SK"
                        End If
                    Else
                        cP = "X"

                        If x <> iB Or arr(iB+3) = "W" Or arr(iB+3) = "A" Or _
                        arr(iB+3) = "E" Or arr(iB+3) = "I" Or arr(iB+3) = "O" Or _
                        arr(iB+3) = "U" Or arr(iB+3) = "Y" Then
                            cS = "X"
                        End If
                    End If
                ElseIf arr(x+2) = "I" Or arr(x+2) = "E" Or arr(x+2) = "Y" Then
                Else
                    cP = "SK"
                    cS = "SK"
                End If
            ElseIf x = intLength And arr(x-1) = "I" And ( _
            arr(x-2) = "A" Or arr(x-2) = "O") Then
                cP = ""
            End If

        Case "T"
            If arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "ION" _
            Or arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "IA" _
            Or arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "CH" Then
                cP = "X"
                cS = "X"
                intJump = 3
            ElseIf (arr(x+1) = "H" Or arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "TH") And _
            (arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) <> "OM" And _
            arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) <> "AM" And _
            arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) <> "SCH" And _
            arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) <> "VAN " And _
            arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) & arr(iB+3) <> "VON ") Then
                cP = "0"
                intJump = 2
            ElseIf arr(x+1) = "D" Then
                intJump = 2
            End If

        Case "V"
            cP = "F"
            cS = "F"

        Case "W"
            If arr(x+1) = "R" Then
                cP = "R"
                cS = "R"
                intJump = 2
            ElseIf arr(iB) & arr(iB+1) & arr(iB+2) = "SCH" _
            Or (x = intLength And ( _
            arr(x-1) = "A" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "E" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "I" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "O" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "U" Or _
            arr(x-1) = "Y")) _
            Or ((arr(x-1) = "E" Or arr(x-1) = "O") And _
            (arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "SKI" Or _
            arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "SKY")) Then
                cP = ""
                cS = "F"
            ElseIf arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "ICZ" _
            Or arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) & arr(x+3) = "ITZ" Then
                cP = "TS"
                cS = "FX"
                intJump = 4
            Else
                cP = ""
                cS = ""
            End If

        Case "X"
            If x = intLength And _
            (arr(x-3) & arr(x-2) & arr(x-1) = "IAU" Or _ 
            arr(x-3) & arr(x-2) & arr(x-1) = "EAU" Or _
            arr(x-2) & arr(x-1) = "AU" Or _
            arr(x-2) & arr(x-1) = "OU") Then
                cP = ""
                cS = ""
            Else
                cP = "KS"
                cS = "KS"
            End If

            If arr(x+1) = "C" Then
                intJump = 2
            End If

        Case "Z"
            If arr(x+1) = "H" Then
                cP = "J"
                cS = "J"
            ElseIf (arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "ZO" Or _
            arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "ZI" Or _
            arr(x+1) & arr(x+2) = "ZA") _
            Or (isSlavoGermanic And x <> iB And arr(x-1) = "T") Then
                cP = "S"
                cS = "TS"
            Else
                cP = "S"
                cS = "S"
            End If
    End Select

    strPrimary = strPrimary & cP
    strSecondary = strSecondary & cS

    If arr(x) = arr(x+1) And arr(x) <> "C" Then
        intJump = intJump + 1
    End If
    x = x + intJump
Loop

For i = 1 To intThreshhold
    strPrimary = strPrimary & " "
    strSecondary = strSecondary & " "
Next

DoubleMetaphone = Left(strPrimary, intThreshhold) & Left(strSecondary, intThreshhold)
End Function
```

The function shows up in excel, but I am getting

```
Compile error:

Invalid outside procedure.
```

How to fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the MsgBox in a Sub procedure.

```
Sub Whatever()
    MsgBox DoubleMetaphone(InputBox("Enter String"), 6)
End Sub
```